# Asp.net allow access only through routes?

Tags: asp.net, url-routing

I am using URL rewrite to make user-friendly URL's. So `www.mysite.som/search` is being handled by `www.mysite/search.aspx` correctly. But there is one more thing I want. I want to prevent direct access to my page `search.aspx`. So, if someone enters www.mysite.com/search.aspx, he should be redirected to `www.mysite.com/search` instead.

What have I tried?

```
<rewrite>
<rule name="Redirect to friendly" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="^(.*)\.aspx$" />
  <action type="Redirect" url="{R:1}" />
</rule>
</rewrite>
```

But its not working.