# Handle This type of page is not served error

Tags: asp.net, error-handling, url-rewriting

I asked this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11483899/asp-net-allow-access-only-through-routes) since no one got an answer, I have got no option but to fall back to less useful Plan B. I am using URL rewriting to prevent direct access to the .aspx page by using

```
<httpHandlers>
  <add verb="*" path="*.aspx" type="System.Web.HttpForbiddenHandler" />
</httpHandlers>
```

This raises the error "This type of page is not served.", how can I instead redirect the user to my own custom handler page? Is there some error code which I can use to redirect? I am looking for a web.config solution.

```
<error statusCode="" redirect="~/notfound.htm" />//What should I put the error code in here?
```

Comment: you have to use customError like <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="~/ErrorPages/Oops.aspx">
    <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/ErrorPages/404.aspx" />
</customErrors> reff:http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/deployment/deploying-web-site-projects/Displaying-a-Custom-Error-Page-cs

Comment: hmmm please show your web.config file

Comment: <customErrors defaultRedirect="~/error.htm" mode="RemoteOnly">
      <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/notfound.htm" />
      <error statusCode="400" redirect="~/notfound.htm" />
    </customErrors>

Comment: Rebuild the solution working, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deleting the bin folder and rebuilding the solution solved my problem.